# Make tensor that has batch_size as a value

Tags: tensorflow

How can I construct a tensor with the batch size as a value? Lets say I have

```
X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,1], dtype=tf.int64)
```

and I want to construct a `tf.SparseVector` with a `dense_shape` of `[batch_size, 10]` where `batch_size` will be the dynamic quantity that is `X.get_shape()[0]`. In my app, `batch_size` is dynamic between valuations.

If I do something in my tensorflow graph like

```
batch_size = X.get_shape()[0]

dense_shape = tf.constant([batch_size, 10])
```

I get errors. Maybe it is because I am trying to use `tf.constant` instead of something else? Or maybe you can't do this, I don't think `batch_size` is actually a tensor, it prints as

```
Dimension(None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) to get the shape as a tensor, and e.g. [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) to build your new shape:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,1], dtype=tf.int64)
batch_size = tf.shape(X)[0]
dense_shape = tf.stack([batch_size, 10])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(dense_shape, feed_dict={X: [[1], [2], [3], [4]]}))
    # [4, 10]
```